# How to exactly add up 2 values with PHP that are output from a WordPress shortcode

Tags: php, wordpress, math

For a personal project, I have 2 gravity forms. I am using this plugin that allows me to add a shortcode with form parameters which adds up all values in every form entry that have been entered in a specific field and gives me a grand total https://wordpress.org/plugins/gravitywp-count/ so I have 2 figures (one from each form)

What I want to do now is use PHP to add them together.

```
<?php
    $first_number = do_shortcode("[gravitywp_count formid='1' number_field='3']");
    $second_number = do_shortcode("[gravitywp_count formid='2' number_field='3']");
    $sum_total = $first_number + $second_number;

    $direct_text = 'The two variables added together = ';

    print ($direct_text . $sum_total);
?>
```

The current value of formid='1' is 10,969.39 and the value of formid='2' is 4,582.92 so the total should be 15,552.31 but my code is only giving me the answer as 14. So I guess it is only adding up the 10 and the 4 so the thousand figures before the first comma.

Can anyone advise?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be achieved by the **[PHP str_replace() Function](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php)**

You can remove the comma from the result you get from the shortcode and store the value in a new variable.

Finally making the code like this:

```
$first_number = do_shortcode("[gravitywp_count formid='1' number_field='3']");
$second_number = do_shortcode("[gravitywp_count formid='2' number_field='3']");
$first_number_sep = str_replace( ',', '', $first_number );
$second_number_sep = str_replace( ',', '', $second_number );

if( is_numeric( $first_number_sep &&  $second_number_sep) ) {
    $first_number = $first_number_sep;
    $second_number = $second_number_sep;
}

$sum_total = $first_number_sep + $second_number_sep;
$sum_total = $first_number_sep + $second_number_sep;
$total_formatted = number_format($sum_total, 2, '.', ','); //formats the number back to the comma state

echo 'The two variables added together = ' . $total_formatted;
```

Comment: Thanks for this, unfortunately it still returns 14?

Comment: Could you explain what you mean? It outputs the value so one of them for example outputs 10,969.39

Comment: @jfar_2020 I updated the code, I made a minor error. It should definitely work now.

Comment: Fantastic, that worked. It outputs 15552.31 so the final question, how can I add the comma in so it outputs as 15,552.31?

Comment: I have updated the answer with the ***number_format*** function.

Comment: That's it, perfect. Thanks a lot.

Comment: My pleasure. :)